# Why are all nonzero eigenvalues of the skew-symmetric real matrices pure imaginary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, skew-symmetric-matrices

Assume that $A$ is an $n\times n$ [skew-symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) real matrix, i.e.
$$A^T=-A.$$

Since $\det(A-\lambda I)=\det(A^T-\lambda I)$, $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues. On the other hand, $A^T$ and $-A$ also have the same eigenvalues. Thus if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, so is $-\lambda$. If $n$ is odd, $\lambda = 0 $ is an eigenvalue.

A curious search in Google returns [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory) the nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ are all pure imaginary and thus are of the form $iλ_1, −iλ_1, iλ_2, −iλ_2,$ … where each of the $λ_k$ are real.

Here is my **question**:

> How can I prove the fact that "the nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ are all pure imaginary"?

Comment: If you are given that the eigenvalues of a Hermitian operator are real, just consider $H=iA$.

Comment: Zero eigenvalues are purely imaginary too :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Consider $A$ as a matrix over $\mathbb{C}$. Then we have that for all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{C}^n$,
$$\langle A\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \rangle = \langle \mathbf{x},A^*\mathbf{y}\rangle,$$
where $\langle-,-\rangle$ is the standard complex inner product, and $A^*$ is the adjoint (which relative to the standard complex inner product is given by the conjugate transpose of $A$). Since $A$ is a real matrix, the adjoint is equal to the transpose, so for every $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{C}^n$, you have
$$\langle A\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle = \langle \mathbf{x},A^T\mathbf{y}\rangle = \langle \mathbf{x},-A\mathbf{y}\rangle = -\langle \mathbf{x},A\mathbf{y}\rangle.$$

Now suppose that $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Setting $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}$, we have
$$\langle A\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle = \langle \lambda\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle = \lambda \lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert^2.$$
On the other hand,
$$-\langle \mathbf{x},A\mathbf{x}\rangle = -\langle\mathbf{x},\lambda\mathbf{x}\rangle = -\overline{\lambda}\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle = -\overline{\lambda}\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert^2.$$
These two are equal, and since $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector, then $\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert\neq 0$. Therefore, we have that $\lambda=-\overline{\lambda}$, and hence $\lambda$ is either $0$ or a pure imaginary number.

Comment: Why can we say that $-<x,\lambda x>=-\bar{\lambda}<x,x>?$ I understand why the lamda can be pulled out but why can it be conjugated?

Comment: @Math4Life: **By definition**. Because complex inner products are sesquilinear, not bilinear. They are, **by definition**, homogeneous in the first coordinate and conjugate homogeneous in the second. Remember that $\langle x,y\rangle = \overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$ is a property required of complex inner products, so if $\langle \lambda\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle = \lambda\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle$, then scalars pulled out of the second argument must "come out" conjugated.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. I appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I saw the following argument in some other thread on this site but cannot find it right now.

$$A^T = -A \implies A A^T = -A^2$$

but for any real matrix $A$, the "Gramian" $A A^T$ is positive semidefinite ([Is a matrix multiplied with its transpose something special?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/158219/96384), [Proof for why a matrix multiplied by its transpose is positive semidefinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1463140/96384)); hence, all eigenvalues of $A^2$ are in $\mathbb R_{\le 0}$, i.e. all eigenvalues of $A$ are in $i\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is real and skew-symmetric, then $\frac{1}{i} \cdot A$ is [hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix#Spectral_properties).

$\bf{Added:}$ Recall that every square complex matrix $Z$ can be written as

$$Z = X + i Y$$

where $X$, $Y$ are hermitian ( the real and the imaginary part of $Z$).  If $Z$ has real entries, then $X$ is real symmetric, and $i Y$ is real skew-symmetric.

Comment: (+) That's the simplest argument.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc: Thank you, appreciate it!