# Is determinant of matrix multiplied its transpose always positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Assume $A$ is an arbitrary $m\times n$ real matrix.

Is $\det(AA^T)$ always positive? Is it non-negative or it can have any value?

#### Edit:

It seems I have to emphasis that $m \ne n$ i.e. matrix is non-squared.

Comment: $AA^T$ is positive semidefinite so it has nonnegative eigenvalues and nonnegative determinant. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix

Comment: Look at whether or not $AA^{T}$ is invertible, too.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/158219/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1463140/96384.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ has a singular value decomposition
$$
A = VDU^{-1}
$$
(note since $A$ is rectangular, $V \neq U$ but $V^T = V^{-1}$ and $U^T = U^{-1}$ and finally, $D^T=D$ since $D$ is diagonal) then
$$
A^T = (U^T)^{-1}D V^T = UDV^T
$$
and now
$$
AA^T = VD^2 V^T
$$
so $\det(AA^T) = \det D^2$ which must be *real* but cuold be negative is one of the singular values of $A$ is complex.

Comment: Can you make your final sentence a little more clearer. I'm afraid I'm not following your point.

Comment: @Pouya just like a square matrix can have complex eigenvalues, the rectangular matrix can have complex singular values, which would make the final result task but negative

Answer (score -1):

In the case n=m (square matrix)

$$det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$$

and

$$det(A^T)=det(A)$$

yes, it is positive

Comment: Well, $\det(A)$ is not exactly defined for non-square $A$, and here $A$ is definitely rectangular, you cannot assume $m \neq n$

Comment: you are right, my bad

Comment: @gt6989b Can we say that T_O is right in the case of square matrix?

Comment: @nam Yes, for square matrices this holds. For rectangular, you have to use similar value decomposition

Comment: @gt6989b By singular value decomposition, $A=U \Sigma V^{T}$. And so, $ A^{T} = V \Sigma^{T} U^T$.

Then, $AA^{T}=U \Sigma V^{T} V \Sigma^{T} U^T = U \Sigma  \Sigma^{T} U^T$

But, I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: @gt6989b Thz for your answer. I know that I missed the fact that $\Sigma^{T} = \Sigma$