# Proof for why a matrix multiplied by its transpose is positive semidefinite

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

The top answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158219/is-a-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-something-special) says

> Moreover if $A$ is regular, then $AA^T$ is also positive definite,
>   since $$x^TAA^Tx=(A^Tx)^T(A^Tx)> 0$$

Suppose $A$ is not regular. It holds that
$$x^TAA^Tx=(A^Tx)^T(A^Tx)= \|A^Tx\|^2_2  \ge 0$$
Therefore $AA^T$ is positive semidefinite.
Is this argument enough, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's enough.

Comment: Two comments: 1) Usually, the definition of a positive semidefinite matrix includes the requirement that $A $ is symmetric (or hermitian for complex matrices). You did not check that. 2) Your argument shows that $A^T A $ is positive semidefinite. It does not show that $A^T A $ is not positive definite.

Comment: What is does it mean that "A is regular" in this context?

Comment: It means the same as invertible. So if $A$ is not invertible, then there are $x$ other than $0$ for which $Ax=0$ and thus strict inequality doesn't hold. On the other hand, if $A$ is invertible (thus regular), then $Ax=0$ only holds for $x=0$ and thus strict inequality (definiteness) holds for all $x \ne 0$. I think that more generally in this case regular means that the columns of $A$ are independent. So $A$ doesn't have to be square.

Comment: I think this piece of answer should be added to the top answer of the linked question!

Comment: Instead of a matrix, can we conclude it for vectors? I mean if $x \in R^d$, then is it true that $x x^T$ is a PSD matrix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your proof. And the result is true even for complex matrices, where you'll consider the hermitian conjugate, instead of the transposed. This is the basis for the Polar Decomposition of complex matrices.

The part where you consider the non regular case, you could have been more clear anda say that, either x belongs to Ker(A), and then it will give zero. Or it has a component in the Im(A) and therefore it must be positive, since the internal product on a vector space is positive definite.