# If $A$ is a real matrix, then $\det(A A^T) \geq 0$ without using eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, transpose

I searched the http://math.stackexchange.com but most of the answer for this question use eigenvalues etc., but I need more elementary ways to show that why $\det(A A^T) \geq 0$ for any real matrix, and $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$. I could easily prove that when $m = n$. I need to show that when $m < n$ or $m > n$.

I guess also when $m > n$, then $\det(A A^T) = 0$. Is it right? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your proof for $m=n$ look like? Note that $\det(AA^T) = 0$ iff $A^T$ has a nontrivial kernel (easy exercise).

Comment: @Dominik, if $m=n$, we have square matrices and so the determinant is defined for both $A$ and $A^T$, and by a theorem in many of linear algebra textbooks we have $det A=det A^T$, therefore, $detAA^T=detA.det A^T=(det A)^2\geq0$.

Comment: See e.g. last answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726351/is-determinant-of-matrix-multiplied-its-transpose-always-positive. $AA^\top$ is a Gram matrix and as such positive semi-definite. Thus, it has non-negative eigenvalues and a non-negative determinant.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/158219/9464

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Binet theorem.

Comment: @asad how does the inequality show up though ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without eigenvalues:

If $A^T$ has rank deficit, so does $AA^T$. Thus, in that case we have $\det(AA^T) = 0$. Now, assume $m \le n$ and rank of $A$ equals $m$. Let
$$ A^T = Q \begin{bmatrix} R \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
be a QR decomposition of $A^T$ (for example given by Gram–Schmidt), that is, $Q$ is square and orthogonal and $R$ is invertible and upper triangular. Then, we have
$$ \det(AA^T) = \det(R^T R) = \det(R)^2 > 0. $$

Answer (score -3):

Why without using eigenvalues? For $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$, $AA^H$ is a Hermitian $n\times n$ matrix. Thus, its eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ and their corresponding eigenvalues are real. Let $(\lambda,x)$ be an eigen-pair of $AA^H$, then
$$AA^Hx=\lambda x \Longrightarrow 0\leq\|Ax\|_2^2=\lambda$$
where last equation by taking inner product with $x$. Since $\lambda$ was arbitrary eigenvalue, det$(A^HA)\geq 0$.