# Prove using vector methods that the midpoints of the sides of a space quadrilateral form a parallelogram.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, vectors

**Problem**

Prove using vector methods that the midpoints of the sides of a space quadrilateral form a parallelogram.

---

**My Solution**

[image]

**B (Conclusion):** The midpoints of the sides of a space quadrilateral form a parallelogram.

**A (Hypothesis):** Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be four points such that they form a space quadrilateral.

**B1:** $\dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{A} + \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{B} = \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{C} + \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{D}$ *where $\dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{A} + \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{B}$ and $\dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{C} + \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{D}$ are congruent sides. The same can be said for the other two sides.*

**A1:** $\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{C} + \mathbf{D}$ *by the definition of quadrilaterals.*

$\implies \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \mathbf{C} + \mathbf{D} \right)$

$\implies \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{A} + \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{B} = \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{C} + \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{D}$

$Q.E.D.$

---

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please review my proof for correctness.

Comment: `I'm going to assume that a space quadrilateral is equivalent to a parallelogram` No, in this context a "*space quadrilateral*" means an arbitrary quadrilateral which is not necessary planar (therefore "*space*", though that's not too common a usage).

Comment: I expect a space quadrilateral is a quadrilateral in an arbitrary-dimension vector space (i.e., a sequence of 4 distinct points).

Comment: I have edited the OP with a diagram. @dxiv, if you're correct, then wouldn't a square also be a valid space quadrilateral? But the midpoints of the sides of a square aren't a parallelogram -- they're a square, aren't they?

Comment: @ThePointer A square *is* a parallelogram. Rectangles, rhombi, squares are particular types of parallelograms.

Comment: @dxiv Oh, ok. Thank you for that.

Comment: @ThePointer If $A,B,C,D$ are the side vectors (rather than position vectors of the vertices), then $A+B=C+D$ holds true for any quadrilateral, so you don't need the parallelogram assumption.

Comment: @dxiv I see. Thanks for that.

Comment: A reference: (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2023382)

Comment: @ThePointer `B1: ... where ... are congruent sides` You still need to justify that $(A+B)/2$ is in fact a side of the parallelogram formed by the midpoints (even if it may be obvious).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If your four points are $a, b, c, d$, then the midpoints, in order around the quad, are 
$$
p = \frac{1}{2}(a+b), q = \frac{1}{2}(b+c), r = \frac{1}{2}(c+d), s = \frac{1}{2}(d+a).
$$

For $pqrs$ to be a parallelogram, you need the edge from $p$ to $q$ to have the same direction vector as the edge from $s$ to $r$; you need a similar thing to hold for the edges from $q$ to $r$ and $p$ to $s$.

What's the direction vector of the edge from $p$ to $q$? Can you express it in terms of $a, b, c, d$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

since $\vec A+\vec B=\vec C+ \vec D$ we have:

$$
\frac{1}{2}(\vec A+\vec B)=\frac{1}{2}(\vec C+ \vec D)\iff \frac{1}{2}\vec A +\frac{1}{2}\vec B=\frac{1}{2}\vec C+\frac{1}{2}\vec D
$$

Comment: But isn't this what I did?

Comment: Yes it is essentally the same, and it is true for any for vectors ( in any vector space) such that $\vec A+\vec B=\vec C+ \vec D$ . You only have to better formulate the hypotesis and the conclusion, And the figure is misleading because the statement is true also for non coplanar vectors.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What do you mean by "better formulate the hypothesis and conclusion"?

Comment: Hypotesis: Let $A,B,C,D$ be four points such that form a quadrilateral (not a parallelogram) in an affine space.

Comment: Ok. thanks. So everything else is ok?

Comment: Properly, you $B$ is not the  ''Conclusion'' but the statement of the ''theorem'' ( but I'm not native English speaker and maybe that I dont known the correct words)

Comment: @ThePointer You wrote `these are the aforementioned midpoints` in the question, but that's wrong. $(A+B)/2$ is *not* the midpoint of any side of the quadrilateral in the posted figure, which seems to imply that $A,B,C,D$ are the vectors corresponding to the sides of the quadrilateral. In that case $(A+B)/2$ is simply half of the diagonal from the tail of $A$ to the head of $B$. You should really clarify in the question what exactly $A,B,C,D$ are supposed to be.

Comment: @dxiv You're right -- I seem to have made an error.

Comment: @dxiv Ok, I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the midpoints of any convex quadrilateral form a parallelogram, and you can prove that quite easily by drawing diagonals of the initial quadrilateral, but I'm not exactly sure what a space parallelogram is either, nor do I know how to prove this using vectors or check your proof as I have close to none understanding of them.