# Example of application-relevant PDEs not satisfying conditions of Lax-Milgram theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, finite-differences, finite-element-method

In every elementary course on Finite Element Methods, Numerical Methods for PDEs, Simulation, and alike, probably, the reasoning goes something like

application motivated PDE $\to$ weak form $\to$ discretization

and this is justified by showing that the weak form satisfies the conditions of the Lax-Milgram theorem or a generalization thereof.

I am looking for PDEs that are *relevant to any kind of application* and which either lead to bilinear forms that are either

- **not continuous** or/and
- **not coercive**

or that **do not lead to a bilinear form** at all.

Please don't resent my lack of knowledge about $\rm inf$-$\rm sup$ conditions.

By *relevant to any kind of application* I mean that the PDE should have any meaning besides serving as a counterexample to the conditions of Lax-Milgram.

PS: please also provide a short argument of why your counter example actually is one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
$$\Delta u+u=f$$
with f in $L^2(0,1)$ and Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: What does the notation $\Delta^2$ mean to you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: @Gustave , are you familiar with a simple example of a physical system governed by this PDE and/or a simple way to show that Lax-Milgram fails for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- [Any employment for the Varignon parallelogram?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023382/any-employment-for-the-varignon-parallelogram)