# Why does the Jacobian of the Bilinear transform appear in the Piola transform?

Tags: finite-element-method

I'm doing work with finite element methods and I often do mappings from the reference square $[0,1]^2$ to the physical quadrilateral by a bilinear/trilinear mapping (we'll stick with 2D for now).

Suppose this mapping maps our quadrilateral vertices by

- $(0,0)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$
- $(1,0)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$
- $(0,1)$ to $(x_3,y_3)$
- $(1,1)$ to $(x_4,y_4)$

I worked on my own and found that correct bilinear transformation is
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    x \\ y
  \end{array}\right]
  =
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    x_1 \\ y_1
  \end{array}\right]
  +
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    x_2-x_1 \\ y_2-y_1
  \end{array}\right]
  \hat{x}
  +
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    x_3-x_1 \\ y_3-y_1
  \end{array}\right]
  \hat{y}
  +
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    x_4-x_3-x_2+x_1 \\ y_4-y_3-y_2+y_1
  \end{array}\right]
  \hat{x}\hat{y}
$$
However, in most cases, we would like an additional transformation that maps normal vectors on the reference square to normal vectors on the physical quadrilateral. I've read that the correct choice is the Piola transformation which is defined by
$$
  \vec{n} = \frac{1}{\text{det}J(\hat{x},\hat{y})} J(\hat{x},\hat{y})\hat{\vec{n}}
$$
where $J(\hat{x},\hat{y})$ is the jacobian of the bilinear transformation above. Why is this true? What is the proof for this?

I started working on my own by trying to map the vectors $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$ to the corresponding normals on the physical cell, but I was already erroneous because I assumed the transform was a constant matrix (which is only valid if we map to rectangle without rotating, but this transform is also automatically diagonal in that case), so I have no clue where this comes from or what the intuition for it should be. Any proofs or links to proofs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate what these *normal vectors* exactly are? (What are they normal to?)

Comment: I believe a correct reference would be any book on mixed finite elements method, especially where the construction of $H(div)$ elements I'd described (typically, it is everywhere). The intuition there is that you want to preserve certain integrals which involve the normals. Cannot extend the comment right now.

Comment: @flawr sure. In that last equation I gave, any of the 4 outward normal vectors to the unit square are denoted by $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ and the corresponding outward normal on the physical quadrilateral is denoted by $\mathbf{n}$.

Comment: @VorKir I was reading the Boffi, Brezzi, Fortin Mixed Finite Elements book on pages 59,60 but it wasn't a great reference. My understanding is they said "here's the Piola transform, it does we want, and here are a couple properties" and then they moved on to Hcurl spaces. They did refer to a master's thesis by J. M. Thomas (who I assume is _the_ Thomas), so I may have to find that instead.

Comment: I'll look for a better reference. I liked the book.by Brezzi, but now I recall that I had to look elsewhere when I was asking myself questions similar to yours.

Comment: @GrahamHarper Isn't using the Jacobian as a transform (up to scaling) the natural thing to do? To transform the normal vectors you actually want to find what happens locally, so the Jacobian gives you exactly this information.

Comment: Maybe the answer given __[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914802)__ is useful.

Comment: The Piola transformation comes naturally if you have a more geometrical view (or maybe physical) on elements of the $H(div)$ space. [This paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2584914?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) might offer some insight to the structure and origin of the transformation but it unfortunately demands some knowledge from differential geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we consider the normal vector we only care what happens locally, and this is exactly what the Jacobian lets us do: It tells us how a transformation behaves locally. So it is just a matter of plugging the right definitions into the transform and seing what we get out of it:

First let's write down the Jacobian.

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
(x_2-x_1) + (x_4-x_3-x_2+x_1)\hat y  &
(x_3-x_1) + (x_4-x_3-x_2+x_1)\hat x \\
(y_2-y_1) + (y_4-y_3-y_2+y_1)\hat y  &
(y_3-y_1) + (y_4-y_3-y_2+y_1)\hat x \\\end{bmatrix}$$

For simplicity I will write $p_i = (x_i, y_i)^t$.

Let us consider the first edge between $p_1$ and $p_2$ where $\hat y=0$.

In this case $\hat n=(0,-1)$. So for any point on this edge $\hat n$ is definde by the difference $\hat n = \hat q - \hat p$. between $\hat p = (\hat x, 0)$ and $\hat q = (\hat x, -1)$. To find the normal $n$ in the physical space we can just transform $\hat p, \hat q$ via the transform you've given and find $p,q$ which lets us define $n=q-p$ which will be the transformed normal vector (ignoring the scaling factor). We can use this definition of the transformed normal vector because the bilinear map preserves lines along the coordinate axes.

Let us do this: So $\hat p$ is transformed to

$$q = p_1 + (p_2-p_1)\hat x.$$

Similarly $\hat q$ is transformed to

$$
\begin{align}
p &= p_1 + (p_2-p_1)\hat x - (p_3-p_1) - (p_4 - p_3 - p_2 + p_1)\hat x \\
\end{align}$$

Therefore

$$
\begin{align}
n &= q - p \\
&= p_1 + (p_2-p_1)\hat x - (p_3-p_1) - (p_4 - p_3 - p_2 + p_1)\hat x - p_1 - (p_2-p_1) \hat x\\
&= p_1-p_3 + (-p_4+p_3+p_2-p_1)\hat x \\
&= -[(p_3-p_1) + (p_4 - p_3  - p_2 + p_1)\hat x] \\
&= J (0, -1)^t \\
&= J \hat n
\end{align}$$

So we see that we find indeed the transformed normal vector by multiplying it with the Jacobian. (Ignoring the scaling, we can always rescale the vector afterwards.) And I'd expect to see similar results if you repeat these computations for the other three edges.

Comment: I like this approach a lot. You're saying that if we parameterize the normal vectors along the edge as the difference of two points and then transform the points according to the bilinear transform, we get exactly that term from the Jacobian. Thank you!