# Given a matrix M, is there a name for the matrix MM^T?

Tags: matrices, notation

One can make a symmetric square matrix out of any m-by-n matrix $M$ by computing the matrix $MM^T$ (or $M^T M$). Is there a name for this operation? I want to call it "symmetrizing" the matrix, but I assume there is already a name for this.

Comment: Symmetrizing a matrix would generally refer to $\frac{1}{2}(M+M^T)$.

Comment: $M^TM$ is referred to as the "Gram matrix" of $M$

Comment: There has been a thread on this, maybe this helps:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158219/is-a-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-something-special