# Why multiply a matrix with its transpose?

Tags: matrices, transpose

This might be a very stupid question, but I do not seem to understand why I would multiple a matrix with its transpose. I am not a mathematician, but I am very interested in understanding the practical usage of equations:

Imagine I have three products sales Apple, Orange and Pear for the last 3 days in a matrix form called A: 
$$ A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
        Apple & Orange & Pear \\
        10 & 2 & 5 \\
        5 & 3 & 10 \\
        4 & 3 & 2 \\
        5 & 10 & 5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

What will $AA^{\rm T}$ tell me?

I have seen this long answer link: [Is a matrix multiplied with its transpose something special?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158219/is-a-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-something-special), but I did not get it at all.

I see that a lot of equations use the product $AA^{\rm T}$ and I really hope that someone will give a very simple answer.

Comment: The point discussed in accepted answer of your link is that $AA^{T}$ is a symmetric matrix. i.e. it is a matrix $B$ such that $B^{T}=B$, and this kind of matrices has some very nice property (e.g they are what's called self-adjoint matrices in inner product spaces). In your particular example, it doesn't really tell anything much

Comment: It  doesn't have any particular meaning without context.

Comment: Not an answer but orthogonal matrices may be of interest.

Comment: Gilbert Strang discusses the pattern $A^T A$ (and $A^T C A$) a lot in his books, such as Introduction to Applied Math.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are great answers by fellow members. I would like to visualize just this particular problem. Lets say there are $4$ companies $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$ and all of them sell three fruits Apples, Oranges and Pears. Because the numbers are less, I will assume that we want to see the daily sales in numbers of all companies.

Create the table for daily sales:
$$\begin{bmatrix} &\text {Apples} & \text{Oranges}&\text{Pears} \\\text{Company 1}&10&2&5\\\text{Company 2} &5&3&10\\\text{Company 3} &4&3&2\\\text{Company 4} &5&10&5\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Just ignore the words and look at the numbers. The first row and first column are just for understanding. The numerical values of the table represent your matrix $A$. This table tells you the daily sales of each company for apples, oranges and pears.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}10 & 2&5 \\5 & 3&10 \\4 & 3&2\\5 & 10&5 \end{bmatrix}$$
If we just write the table in another way, to see just the sales of a particular fruit from all the companies we will write,
$$\begin{bmatrix} &\text {Company 1} & \text{Company 2}&\text{Company 3}&\text{Company 4} \\\text{Apples}&10&5&4&5\\\text{Oranges} &2&3&3&10\\\text{Pears} &5&10&2&5\\\end{bmatrix}$$
This can be written as:
$$A^T=\begin{bmatrix}10 & 5&4&5 \\2 &3& 3&10 \\5 & 10&2&5\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
Now we keep both the tables together,
$$\begin{bmatrix} &\text {Apples} & \text{Oranges}&\text{Pears} \\\text{Company 1}&10&2&5\\\text{Company 2} &5&3&10\\\text{Company 3} &4&3&2\\\text{Company 4} &5&10&5\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} &\text {Company 1} & \text{Company 2}&\text{Company 3}&\text{Company 4} \\\text{Apples}&10&5&4&5\\\text{Oranges} &2&3&3&10\\\text{Pears} &5&10&2&5\\\end{bmatrix}$$
If by some case there is a partnership between two companies say Company A and Company B, then what will be the total fruit sales?
$$\text{Total fruit sales for the partnership} = \text{No of total apples + No of total oranges + No of total pears}$$

**Total fruit sales for the partnership = Company 1 Apples X Company 2 Apples + Company 1 Oranges X Company 2 Oranges + Company 1 Pears X Company 2 Pears**
$$\text{Total fruit sales for the partnership} = 10X5 + 2X3 + 5X10=106$$
So the total sales of fruits for the partnership of Company A and Company B is $106$. 
This is nothing but the second element of the product $AA^T$.

$$AA^T=\begin{bmatrix}10 & 2&5 \\5 & 3&10 \\4 & 3&2\\5 & 10&5 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}10 & 5&4&5 \\2 &3& 3&10 \\5 & 10&2&5\\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}129&106&56&85 \\106&134&49&105 \\56&49&29&60\\ 85&105&60&150\end{bmatrix}$$

What does this product show? This product can be visualized as the total sales chart of each company as well as the total sales of mutual parnterships of companies. 
$$\begin{bmatrix} &\text {Company 1} & \text{Company 2}&\text{Company 3}&\text{Company 4} \\\text{Company 1}&129&106&56&85\\\text{Company 2} &106&134&49&105\\\text{Company 3} &56&49&29&60\\\text{Company 4} &85&105&60&150\\\end{bmatrix}$$

**Crucial points to observe:**

1. The diagonal elements of the matrix $AA^T$ are all just the squared sum of individual companies. For example the first element is the strength of sales of Company 1 and so on.
2. Each non diagonal element shows the total sales that would result due to the partnership between two companies. For example the second element of $AA^T$ is the total sales produced due to the partnership between Company 1 and Company 2.
3. The matrix $AA^T$ is symmetric, which can be visualized using the fact that the total sales due to the partnership of Company 1 and Company 2 is same as that of Company 2 and Company 1.
4. Useful insight from $AA^T$is that check the diagonal elements , whichever is the maximum, you can confirm that Company is stronger in sales. Another useful insight is you can check whether partnership with a particular company is beneficial or not. For example, Company 3 is having the lowest sales individually, so it is beneficial for Company 3 to form a partnership with Company 4 because the total sales would be 60 which is more than double of what Company 3 can have. So, we can check which partnerships would be most beneficial.
5. Diagonal elements: (A measure of) Individual strengths, Non Diagonal Elements: Partnership strengths.

Hope this helps...

Comment: SNEHIL SANYAL how can $AA^T$ represent total fruit sales resulting from partnerships when each entry has units squared, and total fruit sales have units linear?

Comment: 85 is supposed to be 95.

Comment: I don't see that multiplying the fruit makes sense, unless this is some sort of breeding program :-)
Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 12):

In your case, $AA^T$ just sitting on a park bench doesn't tell you anything of great interest.

Hyprfrcb's answer talks about units. One of the elements has units of squared apples. Another has units of pear-oranges. Another has units of orange-pears! This by itself should be a red flag that values don't mean anything by themselves.

It can be a means to get to a least-squares solution if you were looking to model, say, how much of each fruit you'd expect to sell on a particular day. (This was one of the answers in the linked question.)

But by itself? It's just a fruit hybridization experiment gone terribly wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Lets consider the matrix $A$ characterizing the values of some variables $a_{ij}$, $j=1...m$ with values at different times $i=1...n$, as in the OP example, but transposed.

If the variables are normalized in mean, the matrix $\frac 1m A^TA$ is the estimator of the covariances $s_{j_1j_2}=\mathbb{E}(a_{\cdot j_1}a_{\cdot j_2}) \approx \frac 1m \sum a_{j_1}a_{j_2}$ for the set of random variables $a_{\cdot j=1...m}$.

If the entries $a_{ij}$ of $A$ have units of $[a]$, then the entries of $AA^T$ will have units of $[a^2]$. This is consistent with the abovementioned.

When solving the problem $Ax=B$, the solution $x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$ is the best estimator (LS), provided that the covariance as defined above, is enough variable to be invertible.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a dummy explanation. Your answer may perfectly make sense if I was a mathematician, which I am not. How would that relate to the apple, orange example?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only association i could figure for the requested construction. And no, this do not relate with the example in the sense you cannot have -2.5 apples per day. Or we can?

Answer (score 2):

It can be a part of a bigger question (context needed, for example, linear regression as mentioned by lhf in the linked post).

Assume that the vector (Q) of quantity apple sales and the vector (R) of revenues on four days are:
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}10\\ 5\\ 4 \\ 8\end{pmatrix}; \ \ R=\begin{pmatrix}20\\ 10\\ 8\\ 16\end{pmatrix}$$
And now we want to find the linear revenue function $R=aQ+b$. Obviously, it is $R=2Q$:
$$R=\begin{pmatrix}R_1\\ R_2\\ R_3\\ R_4\end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix}10\\ 5\\ 4\\ 8\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}20\\ 10\\ 8\\ 16\end{pmatrix}$$

Keeping in mind that the predicted function is not always perfectly linear fit and for demonstration purpose, assume that we want to find the linear revenue function $y=b_0+b_1x$ using linear regression, where $y=R,x=Q$ and $b_0,b_1$ are the parameters to be found. Then the linear function can be written in the matrix form as:
$$Y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3\\ y_4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&x_1\\ 1&x_2\\ 1&x_3\\ 1&x_4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b_0\\ b_1\end{pmatrix}=Xb$$
Now we need to solve the matrix equation:
$$Y=Xb \Rightarrow \\
X^TY=X^TXb \Rightarrow \\
b=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY=\\
\left[\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&x_1\\ 1&x_2\\ 1&x_3\\ 1&x_4\end{pmatrix}\right]^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3\\ y_4\end{pmatrix}=\\
\left[\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\10&5&4&8\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&10\\ 1&5\\ 1&4\\ 1&8\end{pmatrix}\right]^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\10&5&4&8\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}20\\ 10\\ 8\\ 16\end{pmatrix}=\\
\left[\begin{pmatrix}4&27\\27&205\end{pmatrix}\right]^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}54\\410\end{pmatrix}=\\
\frac{1}{91}\begin{pmatrix}205&-27\\ -27&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}54\\410\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b_0\\b_1\end{pmatrix}$$
as expected: $y=0+2x \iff R=2Q$.