# Matrix multiplied by its transpose

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

I've just done a matrix multiplication question and an interesting thing popped up. That is $MM^T=symmetric $ for the specific matrix we were given. Is this a general property or something special?

Comment: Being symmetric is something special for $MM^T$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158219/is-a-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-something-special). In general, $MN$ is not symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

It is general:$$(MM^T)^T=(M^T)^TM^T=MM^T.$$