# Prove that the eigenvalues of skew-symmetric matrices are purely imaginary numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, skew-symmetric-matrices

Prove that all of the eigenvalues of skew-symmetric matrix are complex numbers with the real part equal to $0$. Has anyone got a clue how to do it?

Comment: The tag ([tag:theorem-provers]) is for questions about software designed for checking formal proofs or assisting with writing them, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/theorem-provers/info). It is not intended for all questions which are about proofs of theorems.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57100/96384

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The eigenvalue problem for a skew-symmetric matrix $M$ is
\begin{align}M\textbf{x}
&=\lambda \textbf{x}\\
\left(M\textbf{x}^*\right)^T\textbf{x}&=\left(\lambda^*\textbf{x}^*\right)^T\textbf{x}\\
\left(\textbf{x}^*\right)^TM^T\textbf{x}&=\lambda^*\left(\textbf{x}^*\right)^T\textbf{x}\\
\left(\textbf{x}^*\right)^T\left(-M\right)\textbf{x}&=\lambda^*\left(\textbf{x}^*\right)^T\textbf{x}\\
\left(\textbf{x}^*\right)^T\left(-\lambda\textbf{x}\right)&=\lambda^*\left(\textbf{x}^*\right)^T\textbf{x}\\
-\lambda\|\textbf{x}\|^2&=\lambda^*\|\textbf{x}\|^2\\
-\lambda&=\lambda^*\\
\therefore \Re(\lambda)&=0
\end{align}

where we have used the notation $^*$ for complex conjugation and $^T$ for transposition. From line 3 to line 4, we use the property of a skew-symmetric matrix: $M^T=-M$. The conclusion is equivalent to saying that $\lambda$ is either $0$ or pure imaginary.

Comment: I don't know where you gone wrong in proving above but the result is only true for real skew symmetric matrices,for counter example consider the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & i\\ -i & 0\end{pmatrix}$, its eigen values 1,-1.

Comment: @Drmosthene if matrix is not real than you cannot move from line 2 to line 3,if I am not wrong?let me know your views in this regard....

Comment: Hi @lbs indeed you have just given an example of a complex skew-symmetric matrix having real eigenvalues; the statement in OP's question is in fact only true for real skew-symmetric matrices (which I assume here in my answer).

Comment: you have not mentioned that you have taken real symmetric matrix,neither OP mentioned such things,so firstly we should have made OP's Question correct,that's why I raised this question

Answer (score 9):

$S$ being skew-symmetric means $S+S^{*}=0$, therefore $\forall x$ holds $x^{*}(S+S^{*})x = 0$. Assume $v$ is an eigenvector, hence $Sv = \lambda v$ and $v\neq 0$. Then, $v^{*}(S+S^{*})v = v^{*}Sv + v^{*}S^{*}v = v^{*}\lambda v + (Sv)^{*} v  = \lambda v^{*} v + \bar{\lambda} v^{*} v = (\lambda + \bar{\lambda})v^{*}v = 0$, which means $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda) =0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: If $A$ is a skew-symmetric matrix then what can you say about the conjugate transpose of $B=iA$ ?