# Let $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, $B$ is a real antisymmetric matrix, $A^2 = B^2$, prove $A = B = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a real symmetric matrix, $\boldsymbol{B}$ is a real antisymmetric matrix, $\boldsymbol{A}^2 = \boldsymbol{B}^2$, prove $\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{B} = \boldsymbol{0}$.

---

I tried the second-order matrix.
Let $\boldsymbol{A} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{12} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$,
$\boldsymbol{B} = \begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12} \\ {-b_{12}} & b_{22} \end{bmatrix}$, $a_{ij}, b_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$.

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{A}^2 &= \begin{bmatrix} {a_{11}^2 + a_{12}^2} & {a_{11}a_{12} + a_{12}a_{22}} \\ {a_{11}a_{12} + a_{12}a_{22}} & {a_{12}^2 + a_{22}^2} \end{bmatrix} \\
\boldsymbol{B}^2 &= \begin{bmatrix} {b_{11}^2 - b_{12}^2} & {b_{11}b_{12} + b_{12}b_{22}} \\ {-b_{11}b_{12} - b_{12}b_{22}} & {-b_{12}^2 + b_{22}^2} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Because $\boldsymbol{A}^2 = \boldsymbol{B}^2$, I got
\begin{align}
a_{11}^2 + a_{12}^2 &= b_{11}^2 - b_{12}^2 \\
a_{11}a_{12} + a_{12}a_{22} &= b_{11}b_{12} + b_{12}b_{22} \\
a_{11}a_{12} + a_{12}a_{22} &= -b_{11}b_{12} - b_{12}b_{22} \\
a_{12}^2 + b_{22}^2 &= -b_{12}^2 + b_{22}^2
\end{align}

Hence,
\begin{align}
a_{11}a_{12}+a_{12}a_{22}=b_{11}b_{12}+b_{12}b_{22}=0
\end{align}

I lost my momentum here.

Comment: What progress have you made on the question? On MSE we don't like to do your homework or to just solve problems for you, we're actually trying to help you figure things out, so it's good to show some effort.

Comment: There are other ways to add context if you prefer, such as explaining why the problem is important or interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us denote the usual inner product on $ \mathbb R^n$ by $(\cdot|\cdot).$ Then

$$||Ax||^2=(Ax|Ax)=(A^TAx|x)=(A^2x|x)=(B^2x|x)=(Bx|B^Tx)=(Bx|-Bx)=-(Bx|Bx)=-||Bx||^2$$

for all $x \in \mathbb R^n.$

Hence $-||Bx||^2 \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n.$ This gives

$||Bx||^2 = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and thus $||Ax||^2 = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ .

Cosequence: $A=B=0.$

Comment: Does $\lVert Ax \rVert$ mean the Frobenius norm or the module of the vector?

Comment: @Fred: It can be any norm, doesn't it?...Implicit, Very nice Idea+1

Comment: The inner product induces the norm $||x||= \sqrt{(x|x)}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu$ be a complex eigenvalue of $B$. Because $B$ is antisymmetric, then $\mu \in i\mathbb{R}$, so $\mu^2$ is a nonpositive real number. But $\mu^2$ is eigenvalue of $B^2$, so of $A^2$, but the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are all nonnegative since $A$ is symmetric. So $\mu=0$.
You get $B=0$, so $A^2=0$, so $A$ is real symmetric and nilpotent, so $A=0$.

Comment: Why "$\boldsymbol{B}$ is antisymmetric" implies $\mu \in i\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Very classical fact, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795233/eigenvalue-of-a-symmetric-and-antisymmetric-matrices

Answer (score 1):

note the orthogonality
$-1\cdot \text{trace}\big(BA\big)= \text{trace}\big(B^TA\big)= \text{trace}\big(B^TA\big)^T= \text{trace}\big(A^TB\big)= \text{trace}\big(AB\big)= \text{trace}\big(BA\big)$
$\implies  \text{trace}\big(BA\big)= 0$

using this we can compute the squared Frobenius norm of A+B
$\Big \Vert A+B\Big \Vert_F^2= \text{trace}\big(A^TA\big) +\text{trace}\big(B^TA\big)+\text{trace}\big(A^TB\big)+\text{trace}\big(B^TB\big) $
$= \text{trace}\big(A^2\big) +0+0 -\text{trace}\big(B^2\big) $
$=0 $
$\implies A+B = \mathbf 0\implies A = -B $
so $A$ is both symmetric and skew symmetric, i.e. $A=A^T=-A^T \implies A=\mathbf 0=-B = B$