# $A+ cE$ invertible when $A^T = - A$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A^T = - A$

Prove that if $\lambda \neq 0$ is a constant, then $A+ \lambda I$ is always invertible.

(where $I$ is the identity matrix)

My idea is to show that $0$ is the only eigenvalue so that $|A+\lambda I|$

I have shown that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then so must $-\lambda$. But I'm not sure how to show $0$ is the only eigenvalue from there.

Is my approach correct? Or is there a simpler way to approach this?

Thank you!

Comment: @Arthur  Ah, I'm wrong. Never mind.

Comment: This is clearly wrong. The matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $\pm i$ so $A \pm iI$ is noninvertible.

Comment: @mechanodroid Actually, the eigenvalues of your matrix are $\pm i$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks. So $\lambda$ in the question is assumed to be real, I suppose.

Comment: @mechanodroid I have no doubts about that (althougn I think that the OP should have stated it).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, Yeah. My bad. $\lambda$ is presumed to be real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is skew -symmetric. Try to show that each eigenvalue of $A$ is of the form $it$ with $t \in \mathbb R$, (where $i^2=-1$).

Comment: Thank you! I think I have understood how to approach this question from this hint.

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of a skew-symmetric matrix are all purely imaginary. One proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57100/why-are-all-nonzero-eigenvalues-of-the-skew-symmetric-matrices-pure-imaginary), by looking at how the matrix behaves with respect to the complex scalar product using a complex eigenvector of $A$.