# When A is anti-symmetric, prove that if $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is non-zero, $A+cI$ is always invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

As above,

When A is anti-symmetric, prove that if $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is non-zero, $A+cI$ is always invertible.

I've tried manipulating eigenvalues but it doesn't seem to work out. What would be the best approach to this problem?

Comment: best approach is to find a counterexample!

Comment: Please confirm the object of your OP about A symmetric or anti-symmetric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you meant anti-symmetric, not symmetric. If that's so, then all eigenvalues of $A$ are purely imaginary (I am assuming that $A$ is a real matrix). Therefore, if $c\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then $-c$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ and so $A+c\operatorname{Id}$ is invertible.

Comment: It is  a good guess !

Comment: Yes! Apologies, I have edited the question.

Comment: How would you go about showing all eigenvalues are purely imaginary?

Comment: I've found an answer over here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57100/why-are-all-nonzero-eigenvalues-of-the-skew-symmetric-matrices-pure-imaginary. Thank you!