# Is there an $n \times n$ matrix which has all its eigenvalues pure imaginary?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I believe that pure imaginary eigenvalues can exist for $2n \times 2n$ matrices only when all the entries of the matrix are real. However, what if $n$ is odd? Is there still a matrix which has all its eigenvalues pure imaginary?

Comment: Absolutely. Consider the matrix $[i],$ for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are all nonzero eigenvalues of the skew-symmetric real matrices pure imaginary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57100/why-are-all-nonzero-eigenvalues-of-the-skew-symmetric-real-matrices-pure-imagina)

Comment: Are you talking about real matrices or complex matrices? If real, remember that the complex roots of a real polynomial must come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: For $n$ odd the characteristic polynomial is of odd degree Hence at least one root is a real number.

Comment: I am only considering a matrix having real entries.

Comment: So, as several of us have explained, in that case $n$ must be even.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is clear.

Comment: All eigenvalues of the zero matrix are purely imaginary.